# Can anyone identify this hotel in Osaka?

Tags: japan, identify-this, osaka

Long shot, but can any one identify this hotel in Osaka. In fact "filmed" in 1997.

Conceivably the sign across the road helps. (I pasted in a blow-up of it.)

Note: this appears in a "travelogue" sequence on Osaka which features painstaking perfect 3D models of (completely real) landmarks and shops in Osaka in 1997.

[image]

[image]

[image] [image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It appears to show the Candeo Hotels building and the Osaka Fujiya Hotel in Namba:

[image]

You'll notice the square Windows of the Osaka Fujiya hotel, and the sloped roof of the Shinei tower the other side match your graphic fairly well. The Candeo Hotels building seems to be a pretty much exact match from the front (the large open area at the top, the three panel windows on the left with the larger single windows on the right, and then the big blue wall on the right-hand side), but less so from the side. I'm convinced it's the inspiration for the scene you posted though.

Google Streetview: https://www.google.com/maps/@34.6709509,135.5061864,3a,75y,197.83h,130.49t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1si0g2lVbVLYuAzt8grWPj-A!2e0!7i16384!8i8192

The only odd thing is that if I refer to the 2009 Streetview imagery of that location, the middle building was a parking lot at that time. It seems like the Candeo Hotels building was constructed sometime between July 2016 and August 2017. I'm assuming whatever you were watching was set in 1997 but features more modern buildings (presumably after the middle building was constructed).

Comment: BTW *"I'm convinced it's the inspiration for the scene you posted though."* Yes, it's not even "inspiration", it's the exact un-named hotel; it precisely matches where they're walking from previously etc.  You rock!!!

Comment: @Fattie Oh wow! Thank you. I'm not sure why it got downvoted, to be honest. It doesn't seem any worse than any other similar "identify this" question. And it certainly isn't a trivial image search - I just got lucky that I saw a hotel with similar windows to the Osaka Fujiya Hotel when I searched on Google,